# Use Python to sum the data every 24 hours and filter for the data with the maximum sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have three rows of data, representing a time series for a whole year at an hourly resolution (3,8760).
I want to sum the values for every 24 hours/columns and filter the row with the maximum sum.

For example:
`A = (1,2,3,4,5,6) B = (0,0,4,5,6,7) C = (0,0,2,6,14,0)` 
If I want to sum the values every 2 hours/columns and filter the row with the maximum sum,
the expected output would be
`(1,2,4,5,14,0).`

Currently, I am only trying to input the data into Python and create it in the form of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your simplified example with shape=(6,3):

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5,6), (0,0,4,5,6,7), (0,0,2,6,14,0)])
```

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  6, 14,  0]])
```

First reshape the array and sum along new axis (2 in simplified example, 24 in your full case):

```py
b = a.reshape((3,3,2)).sum(axis=2)
```

```
array([[ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 0,  9, 13],
       [ 0,  8, 14]])
```

This gives you all partial sums. Now you can get indexes where there sum is biggest for a given column:

```py
idx = np.argmax(b, axis=0)
```

```
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Now you can select values from the initial array according to this index:

```py
a.reshape((3,3,2))[idx, range(a.shape[1]//2), :].reshape((6,))
```

```
array([ 1,  2,  4,  5, 14,  0])
```

Which gives the answer you wanted.

#### Final solution

You can write it all in this routine:

```py
def filter_row_cols(a, period = 2):
  rshape = (a.shape[0], a.shape[1]//period, period)
  idx = np.argmax(a.reshape(rshape).sum(axis=2), axis=0)
  result = a.reshape(rshape)[idx, range(a.shape[1]//period), :].reshape((a.shape[1],))
  return result
```

```
array([ 1,  2,  4,  5, 14,  0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
However, when I try to sum the data every 3 hours per column and filter for the row with the maximum sum, I encounter an error when running the final step "reshape".
"shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,) "

Comment: Fixed. The last operation to obtain the result based on index. I tested it for different values of `period` variable. Try now.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help. It has been applicable to my research, and it has been very helpful for both me and my fellow student.

Comment: I am glad to hear that! I will appreciate also if you accept and vote for the answer then.